# Firebase Authentication reassigned UIDs of existing users on migration to a new version of an Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I store user data in a Firestore document, and for the document's ID I use the user's UID provided by Firebase Authentication. So to access the user data, I call `fAuth.currentUser.uid` and provide the string to the query.
The old version of the app was written in Java, and recently I translated it to Kotlin, creating a new project in Android Studio for that, though it's still connected to the same Firebase project. New users register and use the app just fine. Existing users, however, can't access their data (which is crucial for the app's functionality), because the call for UID returns a different value, and the Firestore query returns a non-existing snapshot.
I use authentication with email and password. Both of them stay the same, the old users login successfully, but as soon as the app needs the user data from the database, it crashes.

I guess there is no way to get back to the previous UID, so I am just curious about what has happened. The only differences between Java and Kotlin projects that I could identify are the app's namespace and the *rootProject.name* variable from the *settings.gradle* file.
Can anyone please explain why the existing users got new UIDs?

Edit 1: I use Firebase SDK Authentication with email and password

```
fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Edit 2: what leads up to the crash:
from a data source, the app listens to a Firestore document containing the user data, and transmits it to a repository as a flow:

```
fun getUserFlow(): Flow<DocumentSnapshot?> =

    if (fAuth.getUserObject() != null) {
        fStore.collection("usuarios")
            .document(fAuth.getUserObject()!!.uid)
            .snapshotAsFlow()
    } else {
        flowOf(null)
    }
```

the repository collects the flow and stores the data contained in the snapshot locally, in the form of a Proto DataStore object:

```
private fun collectUserFlow() {
    appScope.launch {
        fStoreSource.getUserFlow()
            .catch {
                currentCoroutineContext().cancel(null)
            }
            .collect { userSnapshot ->
                updateUserData(userSnapshot)
            }
    }
}

private suspend fun updateUserData(userSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot?) {

    if (userSnapshot != null) {

        userDataStore.updateData { user ->
            user.toBuilder()
                .setNombre(userSnapshot.getString(KEY_NOMBRE))
                .setTelefono(userSnapshot.getString(KEY_TELEFONO))
                .setEmail(userSnapshot.getString(KEY_EMAIL))
                .setToken(userSnapshot.getString(KEY_TOKEN))
                .setMesa(userSnapshot.getString(KEY_MESA))
                .setIsPresent(userSnapshot.getBoolean(KEY_IS_PRESENT)!!)
                .setBonos(userSnapshot.getLong(KEY_BONOS)!!)
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

For the new users, who just downloaded the Kotlin version, the code works perfectly fine. For the existing users, who migrated from the Java version to the Kotlin version, after they logged in successfully (i.e. the transmitted flow of the userSnapshot is not null), trying to update the userDataStore produces a NullPointerException:

```
2023-01-13 11:17:46.312 20966-21215/com.cafeyvinowinebar.Cafe_y_Vino E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.cafeyvinowinebar.Cafe_y_Vino, PID: 20966
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
    at com.cafeyvinowinebar.cafe_y_vino_client.UserData.setNombre(UserData.java:46)
    at com.cafeyvinowinebar.cafe_y_vino_client.UserData.access$100(UserData.java:9)
    at com.cafeyvinowinebar.cafe_y_vino_client.UserData$Builder.setNombre(UserData.java:428)
    at com.cafeyvinowinebar.cafe_y_vino_client.data.repositories.UserDataRepository$updateUserData$2.invokeSuspend(UserDataRepository.kt:340)
    at com.cafeyvinowinebar.cafe_y_vino_client.data.repositories.UserDataRepository$updateUserData$2.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.cafeyvinowinebar.cafe_y_vino_client.data.repositories.UserDataRepository$updateUserData$2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$transformAndWrite$newData$1.invokeSuspend(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:402)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$transformAndWrite$newData$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$transformAndWrite$newData$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:169)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.transformAndWrite(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:402)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.handleUpdate(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:276)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.access$handleUpdate(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:76)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$3.invokeSuspend(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:242)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$3.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$3.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
    at androidx.datastore.core.SimpleActor$offer$2.invokeSuspend(SimpleActor.kt:122)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@9ab40ad, Dispatchers.IO]
```

Basically, the get methods called on the snapshot return null.

To understand the issue better, I edited the updateUserData() a bit:

```
private suspend fun updateUserData(userSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot?) {

    if (userSnapshot != null) {
        
        if (!userSnapshot.exists()) {

            Log.d(TAG, "updateUserData: snapshot doesn't exist!")
            Log.d(TAG, "updateUserData: snapshot's ID: ${userSnapshot.id}")
            Log.d(TAG, "updateUserData: current user's UID: ${fAuthSource.getUserObject()!!.uid}")
            
        } else {

            userDataStore.updateData { user ->
                user.toBuilder()
                    .setNombre(userSnapshot.getString(KEY_NOMBRE))
                    .setTelefono(userSnapshot.getString(KEY_TELEFONO))
                    .setEmail(userSnapshot.getString(KEY_EMAIL))
                    .setToken(userSnapshot.getString(KEY_TOKEN))
                    .setMesa(userSnapshot.getString(KEY_MESA))
                    .setIsPresent(userSnapshot.getBoolean(KEY_IS_PRESENT)!!)
                    .setBonos(userSnapshot.getLong(KEY_BONOS)!!)
                    .build()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the log reads:

```
2023-01-13 11:28:31.744 27734-28131/com.cafeyvinowinebar.Cafe_y_Vino D/UserDataRepository: updateUserData: snapshot doesn't exist!
2023-01-13 11:28:31.744 27734-28131/com.cafeyvinowinebar.Cafe_y_Vino D/UserDataRepository: updateUserData: snapshot's ID: gLYjEBJeMwRi5LgBSgztgqF7XYg2
2023-01-13 11:28:31.744 27734-28131/com.cafeyvinowinebar.Cafe_y_Vino D/UserDataRepository: updateUserData: current user's UID: gLYjEBJeMwRi5LgBSgztgqF7XYg2
```

To sum up the problem: from the Firebase Authentication the app gets the current user's UID and queries the Firstore db for the user's document, stored under their UID. But since the current UID is not the UID under which the user initially signed in and stored their data, the document's snapshot returns empty, and the user can't access their data.

Edit 3: Also it's important to add, that before I updated the app to the Kotlin version on Google Play, I lost my keystore file and had to request a new upload key. So the upload key of the Kotlin version is different from that of the Java version. Can it be the source of the issue?

Comment: What type of provider are you using to sign these users in to Firebase?

Comment: "it crashes" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Please also edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It's Firebase SDK Authentication with email and password

Comment: @AlexMamo Hello, Alex, I edited the question, hope it helps. Could it be that the two versions of the app have different SHA-1 fingerprints, thus, when an old user logs in from the new version, the system thinks it's a different app and reassigns the UID?

Comment: Could it be that `userSnapshot.getString(KEY_NOMBRE)` returns `null`, for example because `userSnapshot` doesn't have a `KEY_NOMBRE`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's exactly what happens. Moreover, the snapshot doesn't have any values, because the current UID is not the same as the UID under which the data was stored initially. So the interesting part here is not the crash itself, it's why Firebase Authentication reassigns the UID of an existing user.

Comment: You already posted that specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101137/firebase-authentication-reassigned-uids-of-existing-users-on-migration-to-a-new, so let's not repeat it here. If there's no document for the current UID, you can't read a user object from that - which is what the error message seems to indicate.